# Problem combining a draggable NSView with SwiftUI components

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsview

I have a NSView-class written using Cocoa:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

final class EntityViewImpl: NSViewRepresentable {

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<EntityViewImpl>) -> EntityView {
        return EntityView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: EntityView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<EntityViewImpl>) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

class EntityView: NSView {

    var oldMousePosition: NSPoint = .zero
    var oldFrameOrigin: NSPoint = .zero

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        NSColor.white.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        self.oldFrameOrigin = self.frame.origin
        self.oldMousePosition = event.locationInWindow
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        let pointInSuperview = event.locationInWindow
        self.frame.origin = NSPoint(x: oldFrameOrigin.x + (pointInSuperview.x - oldMousePosition.x),
                                    y: oldFrameOrigin.y + (pointInSuperview.y - oldMousePosition.y))
    }
}
```

and I want to use this class inside a SwiftUI View-body like:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            EntityViewImpl()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}
```

This works fine and I can also drag around the `EntityView`. However, I can only "grab" it inside of it's original frame. If I drag it outside of the bounds, the mouse event will no longer trigger on the parts of the view that are outside of the original frame. Do I have to somehow "tell" the ContentView that the NSView moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you are using SwiftUI, you need to move the superview of EntityView, like this:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    self.oldFrameOrigin = self.superview!.frame.origin
    self.oldMousePosition = self.superview!.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: self)
}

override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    let pointInSuperview = self.superview!.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: self)
    self.superview!.frame.origin = NSPoint(x: oldFrameOrigin.x + (pointInSuperview.x - oldMousePosition.x),
                                y: oldFrameOrigin.y + (-pointInSuperview.y + oldMousePosition.y))
}
```